# how to draw a circle using ActionScript 

Tags: actionscript-3

how to draw a circle using action script (as a component) i tried some xample did not work....i need to add this circle in a panel

Answer (score 2):

```
// Draw a simple circle, gray, with a radius of 24 px

var circleColor:uint = 0xCCCCCC;
var radius:uint = 24;
var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill(circleColor);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius);
circle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(circle);
```

You can substitute beginLine and endLine instead of beginFill and endFill if you just want the circle's outer edge.

Comment: Error: Acces
of undefined property circle. am getting this error wht to do

Comment: Sorry, I may have assumed too much about your level of knowledge. As Adrian points out, you need to be extending a UIComponent class and overriding updateDisplayList.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a class derived from UIComponent
2. Override the updateDisplayList() method inside your component and draw the circle
3. Add an instance of your component in the panel;

Component class:

```
class MyCircle extends UIComponent
{
   public function MyCircle()
   {
      super();
   }

   override protected function updateDisplayList(width:Number, height:Number):void
   {
      super.updateDisplaylist(width,height);

      this.graphics.clear();
      this.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
      this.graphics.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, Math.min(width/2,height/2));
   }     
}
```

Panel component:

```
<mx:Panel   width    = "400"   height 
= "400">

  <local:MyCircle
     width    = "100%"
     height   = "100%"/>   

</mx:Panel>
```

Comment: how to use this example i tried in root folder i have home.mxml and the action script calss in com folder in that have place code as <mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns:local="com.*"  >
panel code here
</mx:Application>

 Error: Could not resolve <local:MyCircle> to a component implementation.

Comment: As I see your namespace definition.. you need to define the MyCircle as3-class inside the com. package, to make it work