# AS3 creating a circle and expanding it by holding the mouse down

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

The title says it all, I don't know how to code a code that creates a circle, expanding it is no problem, I need help knowing what to code in order for it to be created. Please help :)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346137/how-to-draw-a-circle-using-actionscript)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the graphics routines in the display class:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html

it has examples too.